# check box values from retrieved from database table checked and transferred to another table within the same database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do something important right now - I've got a checkbox list - the values of the checkbox list were retrieved from a database - so its not manually inputted - I am trying to select a random set of values from the list which I have to tick - but the problem  am having is that I am not able to insert them values into a mysql database - so I'll provide a screen shot of the table with the checkbox list and then copy and paste the necessary code(s) below =

[image]

the code for retrieving the data for the two columned table is:

```
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1">
    </colgroup>
<tr>
    <td>
        Engineering Services
    </td>
    <td>
        Information Technologies
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <?php

            $list = "SELECT * FROM specifications WHERE category='Engineering' ORDER BY specifications ASC";
        //$list = "SELECT * FROM specifications ";
        //$list1 = "SELECT * FROM specifications ORDER BY category ASC Limit 2";
            $listAHI = $dbs ->prepare($list);
            $listAHI -> execute();

        //while($row1 = $listAHI1 ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $specifications = $row["specifications"];
                $category = $row["category"];
                echo "
                <input type='checkbox' name='$specifications'[] value='$specifications'>  $specifications<br> 
                ";
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <?php
            $list = "SELECT * FROM specifications WHERE category='Information' ORDER BY specifications ASC";
        //$list = "SELECT * FROM specifications ";
        //$list1 = "SELECT * FROM specifications ORDER BY category ASC Limit 2";
            $listAHI = $dbs ->prepare($list);
            $listAHI -> execute();

        //while($row1 = $listAHI1 ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            while($row = $listAHI ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $specifications = $row["specifications"];
                $category = $row["category"];

                echo "
                <input type='checkbox' name='$specifications'[] value='$specifications'>  $specifications<br> 
                ";
            }

            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the code to insert the checkboxes into the database is also pasted below:

```php
<?php
//session_start();
include('dbcategory.php');
//include('insertdata3.php');
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$first_name = $middle_name = $last_name = $street = $unit = $city = $region = $postalcode = $specifications="";
$businessnumbercountry =  $businessnumbercode =  $businessnumber =  $phone =  $phonecountry = $cellphonearea = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
    $middle_names = $_POST["middle_names"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
    $street = $_POST["street"];
    $unit = $_POST["unit"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    $region = $_POST["region"];
    $postalcode = $_POST["postalcode"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $businessnumber = $_POST["businessnumber"];
    $businessnumbercountry = $_POST["businessnumbercountry"];
    $businessnumberarea = $_POST["businessnumberarea"];

    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $phonearea = $_POST["phonearea"];
    $phonecountry = $_POST["phonecountry"];
    $cellphonecountry = $_POST["cellphonecountry"];
    $cellphonearea = $_POST["cellphonearea"];

    $cellphone = $_POST["cellphone"];
//$specifications = $_POST["specifications"];
    $specifications = implode(",",$_POST['specifications']);
    echo $specifications;
}


if (isset($_POST["submitd"]) && $_POST["submitd"] == "Apply" ){
    $specifications = implode(",",$_POST['specifications']);
    echo $specifications;
    $query567="INSERT into emprecords(id, first_name, middle_names, last_name, street, unit, city, region, postalcode, country, email, businessnumbercountry, businessnumberarea, businessnumber, phonecountry, phonearea, phone, cellphonecountry, cellphonearea, cellphone, specifications) VALUES('$id', '$first_name', '$middle_names', '$last_name', '$street', '$unit', '$city', '$region', '$postalcode', '$country', '$email', '$businessnumbercountry','$businessnumberarea','$businessnumber', '$phonecountry', '$phonearea', '$phone', '$cellphonecountry', '$cellphonearea','$cellphone','$specifications');";
    $vttvk = $dbs -> prepare($query567);
    $vttvk -> execute(array(':id'=>$id,':first_name'=>$first_name,':middle_names'=>$middle_names,':last_name'=>$last_name,':street'=>$street,':unit'=>$unit,':city'=>$city,':region'=>$region,':postalcode'=>$postalcode,':country'=>$country,':email'=>$email, ':businessnumbercountry'=>$businessnumbercountry, ':businessnumberarea'=>$businessnumberarea, ':businessnumber'=>$businessnumber,':phonecountry'=>$phonecountry, ':phonearea'=>$phonearea, ':phone'=>$phone, ':cellphonecountry'=>$cellphonecountry, ':cellphonearea'=>$cellphonearea, ':cellphone'=>$cellphone, ':specifications'=>$specifications));

} 
?>
```

Please help me figure out how to insert the multiple checkbox values into the mysql database using php - thanks! I've already got an array for printing out the database which I retrieved from the table and then imploding the arrays when I tried to insert it into another mysql table...where'd I go wrong?

Comment: yoo hoo? anyone home?

Comment: need help amigos! still stuck!

Answer (score 0):

you have the name of the checkbox as `$specifications[]` which will turn into that variable, and each checkbox will have a unique name rather than creating one array called `specifications`. 
so if one of the specifications in your database is `test1` another is `test2`, your code of:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='$specifications'[] value='$specifications'>  $specifications<br>
```

will render as

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test1'[] value='test1'> test1<br> 
<input type='checkbox' name='test2'[] value='test2'> test2<br>
```

this will give you `$_POST[test1]='test1'` and  `$_POST[test2]='test2'`

Eliminating the `$` in the checkbox name like this

```
<input type='checkbox' name='specifications'[] value='$specifications'>  $specifications<br>
```

will render as

```
<input type='checkbox' name='specifications'[] value='test1'> test1<br> 
<input type='checkbox' name='specifications'[] value='test2'> test2<br>
```

Comment: but i'm retrieving that variable though

Comment: Does your code `echo specifications` run as expected?